# Can't Set Tomcat As Server For a Project

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I've downloaded the latest Netbeans, 6.8 to be precise, then I got the download thats packaged with Tomcat and created a blank Java web application. `Right Clicked > Properties > Run`, but I can't see any servers in the `Server` drop down list.

Tomcat is running, I can verify that by seeing the `tomcat manager` on `http://localhost:8080`. I have tried adding and removing servers under `Tools > Servers`, but this still doesn't work.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried installing tomcat separately, that didn't seem to work, neither did installing glassfish. I just could not get them to show up under the "run" configuration window

I did the following :

1. uninstalled 6.8 beta
2. Installed 6.7.1, exact same bundle (netbeans+tomcat). Worked first time

Sorry, but I'm putting it down to either an issue with 6.8 beta, or the installation itself